# Have a scenario like, if a column in a table has multiple values then the validation should "Pass" or else should "Fail"

Tags: mysql

My query looks like the following

```
SELECT 'diff_in_count' AS TestCaseID,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE flag_name = 'tier1' AND flag_name = 'tier2') THEN 'PASS'
ELSE 'FAIL' END AS 'teststatus';
```

In the above mentioned case, it is passing as we have those two entries in table. Let's say I have changed flag_name = 'tier3', it fails, it is happening.

The question I have here is, when I ran the inner query

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE flag_name = 'tier1' AND flag_name = 'tier2'
```

it is not showing me the records for which it failed. Can someone help me on how to write the query to fetch all the failed records from the above case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you compare `flag_name`, it cannot be equal to both `tier1` and to `tier2` at the same time, so you cannot use `AND`. If `flag_name` may contain both, then you cannot simply compare using `=`, because it won't be equal to one or another.

Comment: Do yu mean by _multiple values_ that the `flag_name` column can contain ONE of either `tier1` OR `tier2` OR `tier3`... Or do you mean that the `flag_name` column could contain `tier1,tier2`

Comment: If its the first try `WHERE flag_name = 'tier1' OR flag_name = 'tier2'`

Comment: flag_name should have "tier1" and "tier2".

Comment: Okay, let me be more specific. If the table does not have the both of these columns, it should fail

Comment: You're mixing concepts. Tables contain rows, that contain columns, that contain values. Imagine an Excel spreadsheet - each cell is a value of a column of a row. What are the possible values for `flag_name` (think of values in the cell) ?